# Why is the description of Dwaraka not how shastras tell us?

Tags: puranas, history, rivers

**Vishnu purana, chaturtha anksha, verse 91**

[image]

> Brahma says, "The place of kushasthali will be known as Dwarakapuri"

**Brahma purana, adhaya 7, verses 29-32**

[image]

> Raja Raiwat, after returning from brahmalok, staying there for only one 'muhurtha'; noticed that many decades had passed in Earth. He also saw that the Yadavas had taken over his kingdom "kushshalipuri" and renamed it to "Dwaravati"

**Skanda purana, Avanti khanda, avanta kshetra mahatmya, adhaya 47, verses 5-7**
[image]

> Ujjaynipuri will be known as Swarnasringa in the first kalpa. In the second kalpa, it will be known as Kushsthali. In the third kalpa, it will be known as Avanti. In the fourth kalpa, it will be known as Amaravati. In the fifth kalpa, it will be known as Churdamani. In the sixth kalpa, it will be known as Padmavati and in the seventh kalpa, it will be known as Ujjayni.

- Here we see that the name of the place changes in kalpas but the location is still the same.

**Skanda purana, Avanti khanda, avanta kshetra mahatmya, adhaya 51, verses 3-6**
[image]

> Veda Vyasa asked sanatkumar, "why was Ujjayinipuri known as Kanakasringa and then  Kushthali then Avanti then Padmavati and finally Ujjayini?"

- Currently Ujjayinipuri is in another location to Kushsthali (Dwaraka)

The name of Dwaraka has been changed few times according to puranas, first from kushasthali to dwarakapuri then finally to Dwaravati. Also Ujjayinipuri and dwarika are at two different locations when shastras say they are the same. So is the current Dwaraka the same as how the puranas are describing it?

<sub>Note: I do not wish to offend anyone regarding my question. Our current thirthas are as holy regardless of their authenticity and I respect their location. Being a Hindu, I would never disrespect any thirtha just because they do not match with shastras. Many thirthas have changed locations and this is why I try to find their original location. Sorry if I have offended anybody.</sub>

**Shiva Puran, Koti Rudra Shamhita, Tryambkeshworjyotirlingamahma adhyaya 27  Verse 17 to 20**
[image]

**Vayu Puran adhyaya 88 Verse 196 to 200**
[image]

**Brahma Puran, adhaya 78, shloka 77:**
[image]

Above Vindhya Parvat lies Kushsthali Puri according to Vayu Puran. Kushwarta is below the Gangadwar according to Shiva Puran. According to bramhapuran, Vagirathai & Gautami Ganga originates from Vindhya Parvat. Due to this reason, Kussthali & Kushwarta lies in the Vindhya Parvat.

Comment: Where in the world did you get the idea that Kushavarta is the same as Kushasthali?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The names, Kushwart, kushadeepa, kushsthali, kushawati and kusheswara all seem the same. I am trying to find where in the shastras it says this because I have seen it. For now, I have removed that part from the post, see if you can find other mistakes. If not, try and answer my question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I've updated the post which detailed out  Kussthali & Kushwarta lies in the same mountain.